# Non-isomorphic posets

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Is there any formula or counting algorithm for the number of non-isomorphic posets (defined on finite n-element set)?
I'm interested how to solve task *5, p.4 in Birkhoff's "Lattice Theory"
[the book](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=o4bu3ex9BdkC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [this](http://oeis.org/A000112) is what you're looking for.  Only a few values are known.  I would be very surprised if there was a simple formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jair Taylor notes, the known values (which is up to $n=16$) are listed in OEIS [A000112](https://oeis.org/A000112).

As for formula or algorithm: No simple formula is known. The Brinkmann & MacKay paper (2002), cited in the OEIS entry, describes an algorithm. Basically it relies on isomorph-free generation of the posets, but see the paper for details.